# assignment operator for different types of operands

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

Is it necessary that the assignment operator (`=`) always copies the rvalue into the lvalue or is it completely dependent on the type of operands that it is operating on? Sorry if it is silly but whatever I read, it is written that it just copies the value on the right to the left. I want to get my facts right.

Please give an example in C++.

Comment: You must choose the language to get an answer. It's currently *overly broad*, as in one of reasons to close the question as **not a real question**.

Comment: @tez I think you under the notion that right side to assignment is considered as rvalue. Not always. In statement `a=b;` both `a,b` are lvalues. So, `=` operator can copy lvalue to an lvalue also.

Comment: @Mahesh: It depends on the formal type of the argument, but normally an lvalue->rvalue conversion is involved.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am confused. In my above example, lets consider `a,b` are of type `int`. Then, do `b` is converted to an rvalue for the assignment operation to work ? Thanks.

Comment: @all Is my question still not clear after the edit? I don't understand why there are a lot of vote downs

Comment: @Mahesh: Yes, the right-hand side undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  The Standard says: "For example, the built-in assignment operators expect that the left operand is an lvalue and that the right operand is a prvalue and yield an lvalue as the result.  User-defined operators are functions, and
the categories of values they expect and yield are determined by their parameter and return types.  Whenever a glvalue appears in a context where a prvalue is expected, the glvalue is converted to a prvalue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary that the assignment operator (=) always copies the rvalue into the lvalue.

No. For user-defined types it does no such thing. Rather, it invokes the appropriate `operator=` function.  Consider these classes:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Half {
  int i;
  void operator=(int j) { i = j/2; }
};
struct Double {
  int i;
  void operator=(int j) { i = j*2; }
};
int main () {
  Half h;
  h = 3;
  Double d;
  d = 3;
  std::cout << h.i << " " << d.i << "\n";
  // Result is "1 6"
}
```

As you can see, the assignment operator is free to perform whatever actions it sees fit. In this case, it is clearly not merely a "copy".

Answer (score 2):

It's really completely dependent on how you implement the assignment operator and the composition of the class ... in C++, the default compiler-created assignment operator method for a POD class or struct will simply do a bit-for-bit copy of the RHS object into the LHS object, but a user-defined assignment operator could do anything you want.  It will always belong to the LHS object, but it doesn't have to-do any copying, or could have any number of side-effects if you so choose.

Comment: That's not what a defaulted assignment operator does in C++.  A C++ defaulted assignment operator invokes `operator=` on each subobject (bases and member variables).

Comment: Okay, sorry for not being specific enough ... I'm clarifying my statement to mean POD types ...

Comment: PODness makes a huge difference, to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload the assignment operator however you please but the usual implementation in C++ is something like this:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject& operator=(const MyObject& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
            x = rhs.x;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

The reason for doing this is to allow simple assignment of custom objects. Since user defined classes and structs can be complex sometimes you need to provide a custom assignment operator to do things like deep copies of pointer members.

```
MyObject a;
MyObject b;
b = a; // calls assignment operator b.operator=(a);
```

Note you can't overload operators in C and Java probably does it differently.

**Edit:**

Other things you may want to know as Griwes pointed out is that the compiler will generate an implicit assignment operator for your user defined object if you don't specify one. Sometimes you want to define or declare it simply to avoid the default behavior generated by the compiler.

There is also some usages of the `=` token that will actually call the copy constructor for instance if you modify my previous use case like so:

```
MyObject a;
MyObject b = a; // this calls the copy constructor (also implicitly defined if not provided)
```

It may look like an assignment but the custom provided operator will not be called in the above case. For more reasons behind when you do or don't want to define an assignment operator check out the rule of three on Wikipedia.

Comment: Worth noting that `=` in C++ is sometimes just call to constructor...

Comment: @Griwes: But this question asks about the assignment operator, not other uses of the `=` token.

Comment: @Griwes Technically it would be the copy constructor but I wanted to keep it in context.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I think you shouldn't take the usage of word "operator" from OP literally, judging from the question...

Answer (score 0):

Different languages use different concepts

Java and C++ and C+ yes, this is an assignment unless overloaded by another function

T-SQL = becomes a test and an assignment

Comment: In C++ there need not be an assignment, since the assignment operator can be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Copy is too general of a term.

In C, if you assign to a pointer, there is no copying of the real value but it will save the memory address where the right-hand operand is stored.

```
int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
*ptr = 1; // points at whatever address 1 has
ptr = 1; // points at address 1, containing ????
```

Comment: You could say it *copies* the *value* of the memory address.